# MSVC's (seem not perfect) support for constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, type-traits

I am making the naive wheel of type traits's `is_base_of`. And Here's a minimal demo about my implementation(didn't consider robustness, is_class...).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
struct A
{

};
struct B : A
{

};
template
<typename T, typename U>
struct IsBaseOf {
    constexpr static bool Test(T* t)
    {
        return true;
    }

    constexpr static bool Test(...)
    {
        return false;
    }

    constexpr static bool value = IsBaseOf<T,U>::Test(static_cast<U*>(nullptr));
};
int main()
{
    static_assert(IsBaseOf<A, B>::value, "Pass");
}
```

This demo can be compiled by gcc/clang but cannot be compiled by MSVC.
http://rextester.com/ATOC6638
http://rextester.com/IWU81465

When i type it on my laptop's Visual Studio 2015(with update patch 3). It cannot be compiled either, the IDE reminds me that "expression must have constant value" before compiling.

So I wonder how's MSVC support for constexpr, or is my code wrong?

Comment: I think you need a newer compiler looking on https://godbolt.org/z/xtG77j
VS2015 fails as you describe but the VS2017 compiler compiles it

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22196/static-assert-cannot-compile-constexprs-method-tha.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug in MSVC. Especially previous versions had numerous issues with `constexpr`. [Here's](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22196/static-assert-cannot-compile-constexprs-method-tha.html) [just](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/316043/constexprstatic-assert-compiler-crash.html) [a bunch of them](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22196/static-assert-cannot-compile-constexprs-method-tha.html) for example. Support for many new features is not all that great yet in MSVC. But it's getting better by the minute. You'll want to always use the latest version to try out this sort of stuff. VisualStudio 2017 compiles this code just fine…

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles with Visual Studio 2017 (cl version 19.15.26726).

You could try adding `/std:c++14` or `/std:c++latest` compiler switch.